# How to add a for loop instead of a foreach loop in C Shell Script?

Tags: csh

Does a csh or a C shell script have a `for` loop or does it only have a `foreach` loop?

Can I do the following?

```
for($i=11; $i<=24; $i++)
{
     echo $i
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no `for`-only loop.

However, to obtain similar results, you can use a while loop:

```
 #!/bin/csh
 set j = 11
 while ( $j <= 24 )
   echo $j
   @ j++
 end
```